# Don't show end-date for single-day event; show it for multi-day event

Tags: datetime

I have one multi-entry date field in an event content type.
In the event view, I use multiple date fields with different date types to display the date as 
MMM dd-dd 
start:time - end:time

The view is perfect for a multi-day event i.e.
Apr 10-14
8:00 a.m. - 3:00 p.m.

But for a single-day event, the the view is not desirable i.e.  
Apr 10-10
      
8:00 a.m. - 3:00 p.m.

Can I set up something conditional in the view to display a single-day event differently than a multi-day event?  OR, how can I hide the end date (not time) if it's the same as the start date?
i.e.  
Apr 10
      
8:00 a.m. - 3:00 p.m.